unable to get a response from a cloud run container
I have two containers api and view. To confirm the URL is correct, I made a small test container that called the api's HealthCheck endpoint several times and printed out the result. Which was 302 Redirect.
So I know it is responding within my cloud run instance, but I also see a 302 whereas locally with the same endpoint using Postman it's a 200 OK.
Now I bring the view container in, and it starts up but shows the same 302 Redirect but in the browsers console. The API doesn't show any hits in the logs. It is just not getting there and I am not sure why.
Locally it works via docker-compose which leads be to believe the containers are setup correctly.
Here you can see the redirect to the api with the correct configured host. If the host was wrong, the container would not stand up, so it most likely is just happy with the 302 redirect.
nginx.conf
daemon off;
user nginx;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_min_length 1024;
    gzip_types *;

    proxy_connect_timeout       300;
    proxy_send_timeout          300;
    proxy_read_timeout          300;
    send_timeout                300;
    keepalive_timeout 300;
    client_body_timeout 300;
    client_header_timeout 300;
    client_max_body_size 1024M;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_buffering off;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 256;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    sendfile on;
    server_tokens off;

    log_format  main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                     '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                     '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    default_type application/octet-stream;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }

     upstream api {
        server ${API_HOST};
     }

     server {
         listen ${PORT};
         listen 80;
         server_name localhost ${API_HOST};

         keepalive_timeout   70;

         root /usr/share/nginx/html;

         access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
         error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

         location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|ico|woff|woff2|ttf)$ {
             expires 1y;
             add_header Cache-Control "public";
             access_log off;
         }

         location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
         }

         location ~ ^/(v1)/ {
             error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;
             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
             proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
             proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

             proxy_redirect off;
             proxy_pass http://api;

             add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";

             expires off;
         }
     }

}

When the page loads no data is rendered and I cannot figure out why it is not communicating with the api container.
Both containers are completely open to allow all connections, and there is no VPC. I did however create a test container and another instance of the api and placed them in internal connections with no avail. I decided to leave that approach alone, since with PostMan I can reach the endpoint. For some reason it is redirecting when on Cloud Run, even when using a simple curl command. Using that same test container locally I get 200 OK and response.
In the test container I try a different unreated URL to see if I can get a 200 OK, which I can. There is something about calling my components URL within Cloud Run.
https://api-39579347304.us-central1.run.app/v1/healthcheck
Has anyone had this issue before?
---- update 1 ---
I just created a simple python container that will return OK
https://test-server-39579347304.us-central1.run.app
200 in the browser, but when I call it within Cloud Run via the container that loops over a curl command it is again 302 Redirect and doesn't print OK which replicates the issue. Not sure why still.
----- Update 1 -----
I managed to get the frontend container to stand up. However, I am still not able to get a response from the backend. The backend logs do not show anything is trying to reach it unless however I use its URL in the browser.

Using the URL for the backend provided, I am able to get a response via the browser/postman.
In the frontend, I am calling the backends' health endpoint and trying to print its response, this gives me a 502.

I am trying to communicate over localhost to the declared port for the ingress container.


There's little value (for those who wish to help you) in stating that things works locally and don't work when deployed to the cloud when there are no accompanying facts. What Docker Compose did you use? How did you deploy the containers to Cloud Run? How did you test both deployments? It's very unlikely that there are no (Cloud Logging) logs unless you're log sinking everything and these would be relevant.

@DazWilkin thanks for posted. I add more details, thanks for the advice. The API is deployed via cloud run and the view container I use an image I push to Dockerhub. Cloud Run is not flexible with which node version I can use. What is odd to me is that when using postman I get a 200 ok when calling the API's health endpoint but 302 redirect within Cloud Run. The test container is just a for loop of a curl, and it is also 302 where as locally like Postman 200. I am not sure what or why the redirect is happening.

Can you explain about your infrastructure? Also share minimal replicating steps and logs?

@SandeepVokkareni I have done this and the logs are not useful. It shows the viewcomponent is getting the request and the api component is not. Any request the api receives is logged. I outlined what I did to debug proving it is not the api but is also replicated in another very basic python app.
